# How to remove entire row based on array indexes in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

This is my array

```
0:0 {value: 123}
0:1 {value: 124}
0:2 {value: 124}

1:0 {value: 120}
1:1 {value: 121}
1:2 {value: 124}

2:0 {value: 123}
2:1 {value: 121}
2:2 {value: 124}

<div onClick={()=>onRemoveVariation(0, 2)}Remove</div>
```

And this is my code

```
const onRemoveVariation = (index1, index2) => {
    setVariants(
      variants.map((data, i) => {
        data.map((d, ix) => {
          if (i === index1 && ix === index2) {
            //Delete the entire row
          }
          return d;
        })
        return data;
      })
    );
  }
```

I used filter function for single array, but don't know how to use 2d array.

If want to delete entire row if index 1 and index 2 match. How to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Consider using filter or another array method and not map

Comment: map always returns an array the same size as the input.  Since you want to change that size, try filter.

Comment: Can you please provide some input which people can just copy/ paste and some expected output as I am not sure the question is crystal clear. But it certainly sounds like you should use `filter()` to only get some of the rows. `map()` will always give you the same amount of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a row, for instance by using the `filter` function.

```
const onRemoveVariation = (index1, index2) => {
  setVariants(variants.map((data, i) => {
    if (i === index1) {
      return data.filter((d, ix) => ix !== index2);
    }
    return data;
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**The splice method would fit your situation if you just only manage the row of your array**

`quantityElements` for how many rows, you want to delete and the `index` arg where you want to start your row in the array

Should you try this code block;

```
const onRemoveVariation = (index, quantityElements ) => {
    setVariants(prev => 
      prev.splice(index, quantityElements)
    );
  }
```